# MongoDB Spring Data aggregate average

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Let's say I have a collection `items` and these are the data in this collection:

```
{ 
  "_id": 1
  "tags": ["handbag", "women", "leather"]
  "price": 30
}, {
  "_id": 2
  "tags": ["jewelry", "women", "necklace"]
  "price": 40
}, {
  "_id": 3
  "tags": ["men", "leather", "necklace"] 
  "price": 10
}
```

With the java model

```
class Item {
  public ObjectId id;
  public List<String> tags;
  public int price;
}
```

How do I get the average price of the items that are tagged with `leather`?

I know that from mongodb cli I can get this with:

```
db.items.aggregate([
  { $match: { tags: { $in: ["leather"] } } }, 
  { $group: { _id: null, averagePrice: { $avg: "$price" } } }
])
```

But how can I convert this into java spring boot/data code? The `Aggregation.group()` method is accepting only the name of the field I cannot specify `_id: null` so it would group all the matching elements as one group.

Here is the aggregation query in Java

```
Aggregation.newAggregation(
   match(Criteria.where("tags").in("leather")),
   group("_id") // how to group all matching rows in one group.
               .avg("price").as("averagePrice")
);
```

Comment: what is your equivalent java model for the document?

Comment: Updated the question with the model.

Comment: Try `Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                match(Criteria.where("tags").in("leather")),
                group().avg("price").as("averagePrice")
        );`

Comment: Ah. Thanks, that works great. I knew it's an easy solution that I just don't see. Could you submit an answer so I mark it?

Comment: For others of you that have landed here -- evidently this is not the case for mongo-java-driver-3.8.2 -- Aggregation is no longer a class listed there, nor in the 3.6 API documentation index. And this is only a little over a year old.

Answer (score 0):

In java, the relevant code should be somewhat like :

```
collection.aggregate(
    Arrays.asList(
        Aggregates.match(Filters.eq("tags", "leather")),
        Aggregates.group("$price", Accumulators.avg("$price", "averagePrice"))
    )
)
```

Comment: Would it group them by `price` making the elements that have the same price be counted only once?